# *ngFor inside Dynamic Component Loader angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ngroute, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I would like to use ngFor and ngIf insie the template load dynamic.

I used this tutorel by angular.io to load my dynamic template :
[here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

I have app.module :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [ 
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule, 


  ],
  providers: [
  ],
   })
 export class AppModule { }
```

My second module :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  entryComponents: [
    Template1Component,
    Template2Component,
    Template3Component,
  ],
  declarations: [
    Template1Component,
    Template2Component,
    Template3Component,

  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

the link between appModule and my module by appRoutingModule :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: 'site', loadChildren: '../myModule.module#MyModule' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

my template 1 have that :

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngfor="let specialite of specialites">
      {{specialite.nam}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

everything work but when I use ngfor I have this error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("

          <ul>
            <li [ERROR ->]*ngfor="let specialite of specialites">
              {{specialite.nam}}
            </li>
"): ng:// ........
Property binding ngforOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".
```

Comment: `ngfor` is incorrect. It needs to be `ngFor`

Comment: i think it is ngFor not ngfor

Comment: yes, try there `*ngFor` rather than `*ngfor` you can find syntax [here](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known native property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530748/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-property)

Comment: it's work, thank you